# Titlebar double drawn

Tags: c++, mfc, titlebar

I havea C++ MFC application and when I upgrade my VS version from 2008 to 2013, the titlebar is drawn twice:

[image]

What can be the reason?

Comment: Problem is in the code of your MFC application. Most likely on line 42 ... but may be on some other line.

Comment: Try to compile it with the v120_xp toolkit (right click on your project, then Properties, then change Platform Toolset under the Configuration Properties->General tab.